# DynamoDB scan not returning any result

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, java-8, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a DynamoDB table with about 45k records, a primary partition key (email) and a primary sort key (brand). All the records have various attributes, one is called `processed` and one is called `studentEmail`.

I need to find all the records given a studentEmail, a brand and with processed `false`, I know for sure that at least one row is gonna be present.
I am using the following code:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.*;

private final AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDB;

public void getRecordForEmailAndBrand(String studentEmail, String brand) {
        final Map<String, AttributeValue> expressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<>();
        expressionAttributeValues.put(":studentEmail", new AttributeValue().withS(studentEmail));
        expressionAttributeValues.put(":brand", new AttributeValue().withS(brand));
        expressionAttributeValues.put(":processed", new AttributeValue().withBOOL(false));

        final Map<String, String> attributesNames = new HashMap<>();
        attributesNames.put("#p", "processed");

        Map<String, AttributeValue> lastKeyEvaluated = null;
        List<Map<String, AttributeValue>> rows = new ArrayList<>();
        do {
            final ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
                    .withTableName(tableName)
                    .withFilterExpression("studentEmail = :studentEmail and brand = :brand and #p = :processed")
                    .withExpressionAttributeNames(attributesNames)
                    .withExpressionAttributeValues(expressionAttributeValues)
                    .withExclusiveStartKey(lastKeyEvaluated);
            final ScanResult result = dynamoDB.scan(scanRequest);
            rows.addAll(result.getItems());
            lastKeyEvaluated = result.getLastEvaluatedKey();
        } while (lastKeyEvaluated != null);
}
```

The problem is that it happens that the method is not returning any row, but I know for sure that the row is there and this is confirmed by the fact that when I use aws ui I can easily find it. Am I missing anything? Maybe in the scanRequest?

Comment: did you try to filter only by e.g. studentEmail to ensure the filter expression is working properly and then add more? also can try adding the studentEmail and brand in attributesNames map?

Comment: I don't see any obvious bug, but please try - as Stef already suggested - to use a less restrictive filter or none at all to try to debug why your scan is not working. Also, and perhaps more importantly, you should NOT be using a Scan and a FilterExpression to do this. You should be using a Query and a KeyConditionExpression. It will be much more efficient and cheaper.

Comment: @NadavHar'El if the condition was wrong I would think it would "fail" every time, while this is working fine most of the times and failing a few times. Also, is it possible to use query without providing the partition key? Trying from the aws web ui, selecting query I have to provide it.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the email *was* your partition key, didn't see you had two different "emails" there. So you're right, Query wouldn't work.

Comment: @NadavHar'El sorry it was confusing but I wanted to give the full situation. Any other idea?

Comment: holy... I am here coz  i have the same problem. Scan in JavaSDK is working - only for some and not for some. I can get 2 items when I have 3 items in DB, or I can get none when I have 1 items. There's not pattern on why this will happen.